# Gerrit code review of git repo with submodules? Create a dependancy relationship in Gerrit?

Tags: git, git-submodules, gerrit

New with Git but have a background with Mercurial. Not sure if that helps here...

We have a git design repo with submodules used across a number of other designs. 
Their are users making changes in both the parent module and a submodule as a code update release.

We have methodology to in place to make sure submodule commits are done correctly to keep the parent module pointing to the correct change in the submodule.

The problem is when pushing the commits (parent module and submodule) to Gerrit (using git push origin HEAD:refs/for/$branch) for review we end up with two reviews. One for the parent module, and one for the submodule.

The parent module shows all it's file diffs/patch and then a reference to a change in the submodule with the change hash for the patch but nothing about the files that where modified there.

Is there a way to tie a dependency on the submodule change with the parent module change in Gerrit?  Insure that the parent module change review cannot be submitted/pushed unless the submodule change has also been reviewed ?

Thanks!
Mick

Answer (score 3):

If you enable the [change.submitwholetopic](http://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.14/config-gerrit.html#change.submitWholeTopic) setting in Gerrit, and then upload the parent and submodule changes with the same topic, Gerrit will ensure that both changes get submitted at the same time.

Alternatively, if you use [submodule subscriptions](http://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.14/user-submodules.html), you don't need to create an explicit review in the parent project. Gerrit will automatically update the submodule's revision when changes on the subproject are submitted.