# git review fails in a repo with submodules under git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

Tags: git, terminal, git-submodules, gerrit

I have a repo with several submodules. Here is the `git state` before I try to execute `git review` and send my changes to the gerrit server:

```
▶ git status
On branch 12345_defect_name
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
    modified:   src/submodule01 (new commits)
    modified:   src/submodule02 (new commits)
    modified:   submodule03 (new commits, modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then I have failing `git review`:

```
▶ git review -t 12345
You have unstaged changes. Please commit or stash them first, and then
try again.
```

Stashing does not help:

```
cd src/submodule01
▶ git stash
No local changes to save
```

This behaviour started after the latest system update, before that the messages that there are some modifications in the submodules never caused problems during `git review`. I could find no helpful info using google search. Would appreaciate your help/hints.

```
▶ git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here is that there is nothing to review:

> ```
> modified:   src/submodule01 (new commits)
> modified:   src/submodule02 (new commits)
> modified:   submodule03 (new commits, modified content)
> ```

Your main superproject module has no changes at all yet—not even any updated submodule hash IDs.  Your *submodules* have changes: the first two of them are on a different commit (than is listed in the superproject repository's index), and the third one is not only on a different commit but also has uncommitted work in it.

You'll need to:

1. commit the uncommitted work in the third submodule;
2. add all three submodules to update the stored hash IDs (`git add src/submodule01 src/submodule02 submodule03`); and
3. make a new commit in the superproject (`git commit`).

This new superproject commit could in theory now be reviewed, but the review by itself is probably not useful, as it merely says (I've made up all the hash IDs):

- instead of 3da993f2e63864668ca7ae1a91c351684aec319d use 0f828332d5ac36fc63b7d8202652efa152809856 for `src/submodule01`
- instead of 45a14f578e14ef5440d4bf971a9103795dac0c3a use b908065ea220664270fe3e51fc99b76fdbae71cc for `src/submodule02`
- instead of 4ac22f8cc0976878ac4d15b7c06ed6d242a56521 use 40f35416c17177a23db28b00c4c18a299e63b3bd for `submodule03`

Whoever does whatever reviewing is to be done will need to look at all three submodules.  They will need the old and new hash IDs, but the actual changes-of-interest are *in* the submodules, so that's where the real review effort goes.  Whether your review tools—`git review` is not a standard Git review tool (as there are no such things), though it [is a standard *Gerrit* tool](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review)—handles submodules, I don't know, but see [Gerrit code review of git repo with submodules? Create a dependancy relationship in Gerrit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51414810/1256452)

Comment: "the third one is not only on a different commit but also has uncommitted work in it."

The problem is that when I go down to the submodule which is supposed to have some uncommited changes, here is what I see:

▶ git status

HEAD detached at 4ac22f8 (example hash number)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: @Ina: in your case, the submodule doesn't have uncommitted work. If the superproject `git status` says `(new commits)` but not `(modified content)`, that's to be expected: the submodule is detached on a *different commit* than the one called for in the superproject's index.

Comment: In a few cases, the *superproject* `git status` can be fooled, but in general if you enter the submodule and run `git status` there, this will fix the superproject's confusion, and the superproject's status would just become `(new commits)`.